# How do i split a check box into an array

Tags: asp.net

I've tried using

```
string[] AllDays = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
```

but I want to assign values of 1 to each so when clicked I can multiply by another value

```
<label for="Monday">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="monday" />
  Monday
</label>
<label for="Tuesday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="tuesday" />
    Tuesday
</label>
<label for="Wednesday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="wednesday" />
    Wednesday
</label>
<label for="Thursday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="thursday" />
    Thursday
</label>
<label for="Friday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="friday" />
    Friday
</label>
```

Comment: <label for="Monday"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="monday" />Monday</label>
        <label for="Tuesday"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="tuesday" />Tuesday</label>
        <label for="Wednesday"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="wednesday" />Wednesday</label>
        <label for="Thursday"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="thursday" />Thursday</label>
        <label for="Friday"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="friday" />Friday</label>

Comment: What so you mean by split a checkbox into an array? Totally unclear question to me.

Comment: im not sure do you use an array or not i just want to assign values of one to each day of the week so if monday and tuesday are checked together they have a value of 2, id then use that to multply by another digit.

Answer (score 0):

use different values. when you need it, get the value (3, for ex), divide by the same value (3/3) to give you 1, then do your multiplication.